# VBA - Disable control on another form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Quite simply, I want to disable a textbox on another form with VBA.

I know that I can open my form like so:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMyForm"
```

I can access the value contained in a textbox on my form like so

```
Dim myValue As String
myValue = [Forms]![frmMyForm]![txtMyControl]
```

I can update the value like so:

```
[Forms]![frmMyForm]![txtMyControl] = "FooBar"
```

How do I disable the textbox (as in set the `Enabled` property to false)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an idiot, it turns out all you do is this:

```
[Forms]![frmMyForm]![txtMyControl].Enabled = False
```

Comment: just as an aside, if you don't want the greyed out look of a disabled control, set the `Locked` property to `True`. The user can still click into the textbox, but cannot alter the value